# Pruning Mongodb Data from C# Code

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, pruning, sitecore8.2

I would like to write some C# code that is called from a job in sitecore, which basically prunes all our mongodb data that is older than 1 year old.  What is the **exact** C# code for doing that?  I want to delete just the data, not drop any "databases".  Do I need any specific assemblies/packages?  Would I be cleaning out just our collection*.wt and index*.wt files for that?

Also, there's two parts to this; one is removing data that's older than a year old, and one is archiving that same data.  I would like to export ALL data in mongodb older than a year into some .CSV or excel backup file (before deleting it from mongodb).  What's the exact C# code for that?  Can it only be done somehow using http://www.fourthbottle.com/2015/08/mongoexport-in-mongodb.html ?  If so, what would be the command for exporting ALL data into a .CSV file, not just a specific collection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
collection.Remove(Query.EQ("CreatedOn", DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)));
```

Comment: Thanks!  My other questions were, what assemblies/packages do I need for this, and what's the best/most efficient way of archiving and how is that done via C# code?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Yes, please provide the exact C# code for the backup as well. He wants you to do his job for him, he doesn't want to have to read or learn anything.